# Zend Framework [Forms] - How to make an array of form elements (textbox)?

Tags: zend-framework, forms, element

How can I achieve the ff. in zend using zend form:

```
<input type="text" name="list[]" />
<input type="text" name="list[]" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to get a lot of help with just "achieve the ff in zend". Can you specify what you are needing or what you have tried or maybe show us some of the PHP involved?

Comment: Are you wanting a way to use the form data submitted as an array, or do you want to create a form from an array?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with:

```
Zend_Form::setElementsBelongTo($array):
```

For more information visit:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html